# Pandas: Drop rows with duplicate condition in on column, yet keep data from dropped rows in new columns

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":

                   ["John", "Myla", "Lewis", "John", "Myla"],

                   "Show": ['Show A', 'Show B', 'Show A', 'Show B', 'Show b']})

df
```

I want to have **one row for each unique value in column 'Name'**. I would use drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep="first"). But I would like to **keep the data from column "show"** from each row in a new column, like this. Any suggestions welcom

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":

                   ["John", "Myla", "Lewis"],

                   "Show A": ['yes', 'yes', 'yes'],
                "Show B": ['yes', 'yes', 'no']})

df
```

Comment: I think you miscopied your first dataframe. The 'wanted outcome' is the same as your initial dataframe

Comment: You are obviously right!df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":

                   ["John", "Myla", "Lewis", "John", "Myla"],

                   "Show": ['Show A', 'Show B', 'Show A', 'Show B', 'Show b']})

df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column with `'yes'` and use `pd.pivot()` to create your desired outcome:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["John", "Myla", "Lewis", "John", "Myla"], "Show": ['Show A', 'Show B', 'Show A', 'Show B', 'Show A']})
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df['yes'] = 'yes'
df = df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Show', values='yes').fillna('no')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
Show  Show A Show B
Name               
John     yes    yes
Lewis    yes     no
Myla     yes    yes
```

Comment: This does indeeed work fine with the example data. But not with my actual dataframe, resulting in (" Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"). I did reset the df.index though ("RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1075, step=1)).

Comment: As the error suggests, you have duplicates, so you need to remove those first. See my edit

Comment: Just to be clear, what does drop_duplicate refer to in this command? "If entire row is identical -> keep first"? (I did not expect any entirely different rows in the dataframe)

Comment: Do you have a small dataframe that reproduces this error? `drop_duplicates` will remove the rows that are exactly the same (so every entry for every column is identical) and keep the first.

Comment: Just checked again. Obviously there were duplicates